# Sqlite check for multiple values- Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a requirement where I need to check for multiple values in sqlite where clause. The query goes like this.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM _jobcard_table as t1 " + 
    " left join _customer_table as t2 on (t1._custid=t2._custid) " + 
    " left join _make_table as t3 on (t1._job_make=t3._makeid) " + 
    " left join _model_table as t4 on (t1._jobmodel=t4._modid) " + 
    " where _addedby='" + Globals.mid + 
        "' AND _jobestimatedate='"+curr+"' " + 
    " group by _jobregno order by _custname";
```

Here curr, is a arraylist of values, I need to check if the date is one of the values in the ArrayList, then return that row, how can I do that? I am able to check for one value say curr.get(0). But not sure how to check for multiple values, please help!

Comment: Please fix the [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IN keyword.

```
"_jobedtimatedate IN (\"value1\", \"value2\", \"value3\")"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the basic idea](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/air-tight/azdnr7qsyLM/BmuNlz5Wc1kJ) for passing array to sqlite:

```
// Pseudocode
list = "";
separator = "";
for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    list += '?';
    statement.parameters[i] = array[i]; 

    if (i != array.length-1) {
          list += ',';
    }
}
statement.text = "SELECT blah blah blah WHERE media.id IN (" + list + ")";
```

The code above uses placeholders to avoid SQL injection.  The created SQL is something like `SELECT col from table WHERE col IN (?,?,...,?)` the actual values are then set using [SQLiteStatement.bind](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteProgram.html#bindString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29).

There is still a problem with large arrays: the code should at least check that the number of elements in the array is not to large, say 100 elements.